# "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations" on production server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, web-services

I have been working on a WCF web service, which is used by a mobile app that would send some data to it and save to DB.

One of the test case is that we try to append 2 (or more) records in the app, and the service is called to do a batch insert / update action.

**Everything goes fine when I test using `localhost`, but when we test it using production server, only
the first record is saved, while the other record triggers the error message**

`Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations...store-generated values.`

I have no idea what is the cause and how to solve it. I have done some research and I am quite sure that the related `model/DB table` has NO circular dependency or self dependency.

Below is a snippet of the web service:

```
public void submit(List<SubmissionParameter> param){
    using (var context = ObjectContextManager.AuditEnabledInstance){
        foreach (var item in param){
            ReadingSubmission readingSubmission = context.ReadingSubmissions.Where(p => p.ReadingSubmissionUniqueIdentifier == item.Readingsubmissionuniqueidentifier).SingleOrDefault();
            if (readingSubmission == null){
                readingSubmission = new ReadingSubmission();
                context.ReadingSubmissions.AddObject(readingSubmission);
            }

            readingSubmission.ReadingSubmissionUniqueIdentifier = item.Readingsubmissionuniqueidentifier;
            readingSubmission.SystemID = item.Systemid;
            readingSubmission.UserID = item.Userid;

            foreach (var record in item.Readings){
                SystemReading systemReading = context.SystemReadings.Where(p =>   p.SystemReadingUniqueIdentifier == record.Systemreadinguniqueidentifier).SingleOrDefault();
                if (systemReading == null){
                    systemReading = new SystemReading();
                    readingSubmission.SystemReadings.Add(systemReading);
                }  
                systemReading.SystemReadingUniqueIdentifier = record.Systemreadinguniqueidentifier;
                systemReading.MeasurementID = record.Measurementid;        
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

`ReadingSubmission` and `SystemReading` is a `1 to many` relation

`SubmissionParameter` is just a transmission object as the mobile client will send the `JSON` object to this web service.

I use `Telerik Fiddler` to post the `JSON` into this web service for testing, so I am quite sure the problem is not at the mobile client side.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve the problem though I am not quite sure why it works.

I move the `context.SaveChanges()` out of the `foreach` loop then it all works again for

both `localhost` and production

Hope it can help someone to save some time